# Is there a way to match a value to a range in a lookup table?

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I have two separate tables in an Excel worksheet, as illustrated below. 
Columns `A`, `B`, `E`, `F` and `G` are my input values;
I want a formula that generates the values in Column `C`
(shown in italics):

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Name | Value | Type |  | Type | Lower | Upper |
| 2 | Andy | 35 | *Spam* |  | Spam | 35 | 39 |
| 3 | Mark | 85 | *Foo* |  | Ham | 25 | 27 |
| 4 | Pat | 28 | ***N/A*** |  | Eggs | 91 | 95 |
| 5 | Deb | 93 | *Eggs* |  | Foo | 82 | 86 |
| 6 | Emily | 92 | *Eggs* |  | Bar | 65 | 69 |
| 7 | Greg | 22 | ***N/A*** |  |  |  |  |
| 8 | Gary | 67 | *Bar* |  |  |  |  |

For each row in the first table (i.e., each person),
I want to find that person’s Type based on their Value (Column `B`)
by finding the row in the second table where the person’s Value
falls within the Lower→Upper range (Columns `F` and `G`). 
So, for example, Mark (Row 3) has a Type of “Foo”
because his Value (85) falls between 82 and 86,
associated with “Foo” in Row 5 of the second table. 
Note that Pat’s Value is 28 (Row 4), which does not match any range.

The ranges are inclusive. 
For example, Andy’s Type is “Spam” (Row 2) even though his Value (35)
***equals*** the Lower end of the range for “Spam” (Cell `F2`).

I know nested IFs are quite hard to debug in Excel,
so I’d like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Not sure if that works, because it doesn't make use of the ranges. For example, an A grade requires your mark to be between 80 - 100.

Comment: Well the issue with relying on the third parameter is that anything over the highest value in column F would return N/A. Further to that, and maybe its my fault for not clarifying, the ranges in my actual problem are not clean and sorted like this example. Values between 2 to 5 is assigned to one category, then values between 63 to 70 could be assigned another category with nothing in between both ranges.

Comment: You're probably right

Comment: Update your question to better reflect the problem you are having. Also, does the VLOOKUP solution below not work for you?

Comment: @sudden as always, you shoud add to your Q actual representitive data (as text, not as an image) redacted if necassary to remove sensitive information, and examples of expected results.

Comment: @BigBen I updated my question to really reflect the issue I'm having, as well as the output I'm expecting. Hope you had time to take a second look, thanks

Comment: Voted to reopen based on your latest edit. Though the value for `28` should probably be `N/A`, not `Ham`.

Comment: You're right, sorry I really need to QC my examples before pasting it..

Comment: You could use `=INDEX($F$2:$F$6,MATCH(1,($G$2:$G$6<=B2)*($H$2:$H$6>=B2),0),)`. Depending on your version of Excel may need confirmed with Ctrl+Shift+Enter. Or if you have access to the FILTER function, `=IFERROR(FILTER($F$2:$F$6,($G$2:$G$6<=B2)*($H$2:$H$6>=B2)),NA())`.

Comment: Yup, that works. Tried it on my massive dataset and its referencing the ranges and labelling correctly. I'm going to have to spend some time deciphering your formula to understand it, but this is the right answer. I assume the question needs to be re-opened to mark it as such.

Comment: re-opened @BigBen

Comment: @sudden_clarity_clarence it seems you got your answer.  But in future when you post sample data, post it **as text** (if you feel an image adds value you can post that too, but always include it as text).  Making people retype _your_ data is not OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your source table to show the lower limit for each grade and then use a `VLOOKUP` with a approximate match

---

Update to show how to include blank ranges

[image]

---

### Filter Solution

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to the `FILTER` function, one option is an `INDEX`/`MATCH` array formula, which will need confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
=INDEX($F$2:$F$6,MATCH(1,($G$2:$G$6<=B2)*($H$2:$H$6>=B2),0),)
```

[image]

Another option is `LOOKUP`, which does not need <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
=LOOKUP(1,1/(($G$2:$G$6<=B2)*($H$2:$H$6>=B2)),$F$2:$F$6)
```

[image]